# Salesforce Identity Connect and AD user management

Tags: user-record, identity, activedirectory

If a user is deleted from Active Directory, is the corresponding user record deleted or simply deactivated from Salesforce data store?

Answer (score 3):

Users cannot be deleted from a Salesforce org, the user would be deactivated.